# Rails Devise auth for browser and mobile app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a rails application that is accessed from the browser as well as from a mobile device. I am using Devise for authentication, and I am using token authentication for the mobile device.

I get the auth token on logging in from the mobile app, and I use it with every call that I make from the mobile device.

On the browser, I am using session based cookies. Hence, it so happens that two people can login at the same time with the same username/password from both the browser and the mobile app, and that is causing data corruption.

How do I fix this issue? If I can send the same auth_token with every call from the browser too, then this issue will be fixed, since the last logged in auth_token will take precedence over the other.

Any clues as to how I can send this auth token from the browser for all calls (get/post/put/delete)?

I am not using jQuery or any Ajax calls from the browser.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you mean "a person can log from both browser and mobile app", otherwise you've got a security issue.

Comment: Yes. The same person can log from both the browser and mobile app, and continue editing from either without being logged out from the other.

Comment: How is this different from being able to log in from two separate browsers at the same time?

Comment: @rossta This is not too different...but let me back it up a bit...The login is not per person, but kind of a per account login. And the person(s) can either login from the browser or a mobile device. Ideally, if I only use token authentication for both the mediums, then whoever logs in last, his token will be the latest, and the other person won't be able to do any transactions using his stale token.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to configure devise to use a stateless token for each request.

```
config.skip_session_storage = [:token_auth]
```

If you haven't already, take a look at the [token authenticable](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/TokenAuthenticatable) documentation. There are methods defined there to ensure that the token is valid and re-generate if not. I'm not sure it's wise to use this in the browser, but you could certainly expire a token for the mobile app if the user logs into the browser which would force them to re-authenticate on the mobile app.